# How to get the subdomain name without domain?

Tags: javascript, subdomain

I want to extract just the subdomain part from the url. How to solve this problem.
Eg. if the url is "http://www.example.com" how to get "www"?

Comment: try using js split.

Comment: var location = window.location;
console.log(location);

Answer (score 0):

I would use `URL()` to extract the hostname of the url, then `split()` to extract the domain segments and get first one:

```
var url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
var subdomain = url.hostname.split('.')[0];
```

Comment: What if the subdomain contains a dot?

Comment: how to write a java script for the same?